# DatagridView Not Displaying the error icon or error text?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a win form (c#) with a datagridview.  I set the grid's datasource to a datatable.

The user wants to check if some data in the datatable exists in another source, so we loop through the table comparing rows to the other source and set the rowerror on the datatable to a short message.  The datagridview is not showing these errors.  The errortext on the datagridviewrows are set, but no error displayed.

Am I just expecting too much for the errors to show and they only show in the context of editing the data in the grid?

I have been tinkering with this for a day and searched for someone that has posted a simalar issue to no avail - help!

Answer (score 11):

Check that `AutoSizeRowsMode` is set to `DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.None`. I have found that the row `Errortext` preview icon is not displayed when `AutoSizeRowsMode` is not set to the default of none.

```
DataGridView1.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.None
```

Comment: worked for me also.  btw, here's a [connect post](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/115989/datagridview-errortext-is-not-displayed-properly) that includes a workaround when you still need to use AutoSizeRowsMode

Comment: I notice that setting the `Font` in the `OnCellFormatting(DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)` method to a font size that has a trivial size larger, e.g. `Font f = Font(SystemFonts.DefaultFont.Name, 7.800001f, FontStyle.Regular); e.CellStyle.Font = f;` will show the `ErrorText` in the row header cells when `AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.DisplayedCells;` Smaller font sizes do not work, it has to be larger. Font "Latha" 6.8f will display the error text. So it seems like there is some internal row height calculation that is causing the error icon visibility to be suppressed.

Answer (score 10):

This is a bit late for the original poster, but here what solved it for me...

**Check the row height**. If it's less than **19** it will not draw the icon. Try setting it a bit higher to see if thats the problem.

```
grid.RowTemplate.Height = 22
```

Comment: You can also use the `MinimumHeight` property. i.e. `dgv.RowTemplate.MinimumHeight = 21;`

Answer (score 6):

If you set e.Cancel to True the icon does not display. Which does not let the user know that a problem exists on that line.

Comment: ... in which case you should do something like [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7714126/42961).

Answer (score 5):

The `DataGridView` has to be visible at the time the `ErrorText` property is set.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using *Visual Studio 2017* and your data is not bound to a datasource, then you have to set the **ErrorText** on the **cell** rather than the row, like this:

```
gvwWebsites.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].ErrorText = "You have already used that address.";
```

Answer (score 3):

One more reason the error icon is not showing is, if the row header size is too small. By default, it is 46. If for some reason you set the row header to a smaller size, such as 30, the error icon will not display.

Answer (score 2):

Check `dgv.ShowRowErrors` property.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced similar issue when validating user input in the

```
private void gridGrid_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
```

handler. The problem was I set `e.Cancel=true` in case of invalid input.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else is still searching nowadays: The solution that worked for me was to re-assign the (same) DataSource to the DataGridView, and call the Refresh method on the grid after having set the RowError properties.

(VB.Net code:)

```
myDataGridView.DataSource = myDataSet.Tables(0) 
myDataGridView.Refresh()
```

After doing that, the newly assigned RowError's were finally displayed.

Comment: I found after I was setting the cell's ErrorText - I was inadverently re-populating the Grid and thereby clearing all the ErrorTexts!!! Based on this it was easy to fix **but** it got me thinking how **your solution was the cause of my problem**.

Answer (score -1):

I believe that the errors will only show on editing. What you could do is add a bool column to your DataTable, which drives the display of an image/custom column in the DataGridView, reflecting whether there is an error or not.

Comment: You can set the error text on a data grid view's row at any time, and it should display the icon.

Answer (score -1):

Send an ESC keystroke will force it to show (at least worked for me)

```
SendKeys.Send("{ESC}");
```