# Forcing ErrorText to show in a DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-binding, datagridview

I've Googled and Googled for this already...
When my application starts, it loads a config file and displays its contents in a DataGridView - including errors found in the config file.

So when my method Main() exits, here are some key values:

- `dgv.Rows[0].Cells[3].ErrorText` contains *"Only alpha-numeric characters allowed"*
- `dgv.Visible` is False
- `dgv.Rows[0].Cells[3].IsInEditMode` is False

Here's the pertinent code:

```
    public Main()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        dgvStationConfiguration.DataSource = FileReaderWriter.GetStationsFromConfigFile();
        StationConfigurationValidator.ValidateAllCellsAndSetAllErrorMessages(dgvStationConfiguration);
    }
```

and

```
    public static bool ValidateAllCellsAndSetAllErrorMessages(DataGridView dgv)
    {
        bool areAllCellsValid = true;

        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv.Rows)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
            {
                bool isCellValid = ValidateCellAndSetErrorMessage(cell); // validate all cells in order to set their error text/glyphs; this flag is just to be able to return a summary

                if (isCellValid == false)
                {
                    areAllCellsValid = false;
                }
            }
        }

        return areAllCellsValid;
    }
```

and

```
    public static bool ValidateCellAndSetErrorMessage(DataGridViewCell cell)
    {
        string columnName = cell.OwningColumn.Name;
        string cellValue = cell.EditedFormattedValue.ToString();

        cell.ErrorText = StationConfigurationValidator.GetCellErrorMessage(columnName, cellValue);
        return cell.ErrorText == string.Empty;
    }
```

When the method completes and the user is shown the DataGridView, no red error glyphs are visible. If I click in and then out of that cell (namely [0][3]) - the glyph appears.
I get the impression that the main problem is that when the ErrorText is set (in method Main) the the DataGridView is still not visible.
I'm getting so desperate that I'm thinking of this incredible hack: have a timer go off in 10ms (to allow method Main to exit) to set the ErrorText - then disable (unhook) the timer. That's such a hack I can't stand it... Just illustrating my desperation... :-(
**So...** *What do I need to do to make that glyph show???*

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: You may find a solution in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291475/datagridview-not-displaying-the-error-icon-or-error-text

Comment: @kurubaran, I added code into the question.

Comment: @Saragis, I've read that question/answers several times before posting. None of it helps, except for what it said there: *"The DataGridView has to be visible at the time the ErrorText property is set"* which I think may be the issue (as I mentioned above) ...but I'm just not sure how to solve it...

Comment: Alright, that might be the issue indeed. So when does your grid become visible? Isn't it possible to refactor so that the validation check happens right after setting the visibility to true? Or you could leave it as is but store the errors and row/col values in a collection and apply after making the grid visible.

Comment: @Saragis, I'm not manually making the grid in/visible at any point. From what I see in the debugger, its visibility is set to False (automatically) during the execution of method Main(). Then, once the method finishes executing, it is shown (for the first time) to the user - and its visibility becomes True. So... the following seems slightly hacky, but it works: if I hook the "VisibleChanged" event, I can run my validation then and it successfully shows... (Unless someone can suggest something more "normal"...) Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place your datagrid validation code in the `Load` event rather than in your constructor and the glyphs will show up right away with no need for handling the `VisibleChanged` event.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<KeyValuePair<int, string>> list1 = new List<KeyValuePair<int, string>>();
        list1.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(1, "string 1"));
        list1.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(2, "string 2"));
        list1.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(3, "string 3 is too long."));
        list1.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(4, "string 4"));
        list1.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(5, "string 5"));

        dataGridView1.DataSource = list1;
        DgvValidator();
    }

    private void DgvValidator()
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            if (((string)row.Cells[1].Value).Length > 10)
                row.Cells[1].ErrorText = "ERROR!";
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! Now **that** solution does not feel hacky [(as I had commented above)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31750507/forcing-errortext-to-show-in-a-datagridview/31969907#comment51436304_31750507). Great answer!