# Problem displaying error message in DataGridView WinForms

Tags: vb.net

I have created a user control which contains a DataGridView and other types of controls. I need to validate user input in a DataGridView and if the user enters invalid values inform him about it. I'm validating user input in the CellValidating event handler. If the data is incorrect, then I set the error description in the ErrorText property and e.Cancel = True.

[image]

```vb
Private Sub dgv_CellValidating(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs) Handles dgv.CellValidating
    Dim _message As String
 
    _message = Nothing
 
    If (Not Me.dgv.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).IsInEditMode) Then
        ' ...
    Else
        If (Me.dgv.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).ValueType Is GetType(Integer)) Then
            Dim _intValue As Integer
            If Not Integer.TryParse(e.FormattedValue, _intValue) Then
                _message = "The field only accepts integer values."
            End If
        ElseIf (Me.dgv.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).ValueType Is GetType(Single)) Then
            Dim _sngValue As Single
            If Not Single.TryParse(e.FormattedValue, _sngValue) Then
                _message = "The entered value is not a valid number."
            End If
        End If
 
        If (Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(_message)) Then
            Me.dgv.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).ErrorText = String.Format("Error: {0}", _message)
            e.Cancel = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
 
Private Sub dgv_CellValidated(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgv.CellValidated
    ' Clear any error messages that may have been set in cell validation.
    Me.dgv.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).ErrorText = Nothing
End Sub
```

[image]

In this case, the user cannot leave this cell and the description of the error is not displayed and the red marker is also not visible. Tell me, is it possible to display the error marker and the text with the error description, otherwise I don’t understand what is the point of setting the error description if it is invisible?

Comment: There are two similar questions on SO that might help you: [DatagridView Not Displaying the error icon or error text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291475/datagridview-not-displaying-the-error-icon-or-error-text) and [Forcing ErrorText to show in a DataGridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31750507/forcing-errortext-to-show-in-a-datagridview)